# Why does SELECT * bring down a Cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra, relational-database, datastax-enterprise

In relational databases, the worst `SELECT *` does is causes a connection timeout but it does not bring down the database. What does Cassandra do internally that differs?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't bring down the database. Most likely your heap is too small and the JVM is stuck GCing because of it or you have a data model that is not actually something that can work (ie 100gb partitions).

Try increasing heap size (at least over 8gb is min for most workloads), make sure swap is disabled. Read log warnings and errors. Evaluate your data model for anti patterns (most likely issue).

A no clause `SELECT *` is an inherently bad query (range query) in cassandra for multiple reasons, its best to be able to work within a specific partition on the query